# Lookup calculated field from a choice field in a document repository

Tags: 2013, enterprise

I have a SharePoint 2013 list that contains a choice field [**Released to User**]. What I would like to do is use that field to filter documents in a document repository i.e. show me documents released to individual users.

I've created a calculated field [**RTU**], in my original list, that contains the [**Released to user**] field.  When I view the calculated column in the original list, it contains the data that I expect.

I then created a lookup field to [**RTU**], the calculated field from my list, in my document repository list.  However when I view the lookup column in the document repository list, it is empty.  Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong, or how if what I'm trying to achieve is possible OOTB?

Comment: Is RTU as choice or calculated column? You mentioned both above. If they are 2 seperate fields, whats the purpose of RTU as a calculated column?